# check whether two strings are nearly equal in Java

Tags: java, mysql, search, jtextarea, string-comparison

I have a `JInternalFrame`  form called `LCI` in my java `NetBeans` project called `POST`.In `LCI` there is a `JTextArea` which is called as `HEADING`.When I enter a text in HEADING and clicked the `JButton` called `SEARCH` I need the HEADING to be compared with all the data that are already stored in the database table column called `Heading`.

If some part of a certain data item is matched with the text I typed in `HEADING`, then the particular data item should grab the whole row of data from the db table into the input fields on `LCI`or else to give an error message.

Below is the code of the `ActionPerformed` method of the `JButton` called `SEARCH` .

```
 private void SEARCHActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        try{
            Statement s=DB.getConnection().createStatement();  
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            HEADING.getText().toCharArray();
         //   s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".compareTo(HEADING);
           // s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".contains(HEADING);
            //s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".matches(HEADING);
           // s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".
            if(s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".compareToIgnoreCase(HEADING)))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Finished Searching.");

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nothing similar to the text you enterd.");
            }


        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

But this code seems wrong.An exclamation mark colored in red is appearing before the line `if(s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".compareToIgnoreCase(HEADING)))`

Can any one please tell me how to amend this code to get done what I need?Thank you very much in advance.I use `NetBeans 8.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line to next code:

```
if(s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".equalsIgnoreCase(HEADING)))
```

I.e. just replace compareToIgnoreCase to equalsIgnoreCase

**Update:**
In this line you tries to pass to method *executeUpdate* integer value, but this method must be called with string, containing sql. Please, describe what do you want to do in this code?

Comment: Thank you Anton. I'd try that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HEADING is a char array, but the compareToIgnoreCase needs a string parameter.

Comment: Thank you Shanon  I tried it this way too. HEADING.getText().toString(); if(s.executeUpdate("select * from LCI where Heading".compareToIgnoreCase(HEADING)))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Finished Searching.");

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nothing similar to the text you enterd.");
            }
But it also gives a red exclamation mark.